# How to properly handle exceptions in MongoClient for VertX

Tags: mongodb, vert.x, mongo-java-driver

In the startup method of my application I want to check that the credentials for MongoDB provided to the application are OK. If they are OK, I continue the startup, if not, the application is supposed to exit as it cannot connect to the DB. The code snippet is as below:

```
  // Create the client
  MongoClient mongodb = null;
  try {
      mongodb = MongoClient.createShared(vertx, mongo_cnf, mongo_cnf.getString("pool_name"));
  }
  catch(Exception e) {
      log.error("Unable to create MongoDB client. Cause: '{}'. Bailing out", e.getMessage());
      System.exit(-1);
  }
```

If I provide wrong credentials, the `catch` block is not called. Yet I get the following on the console:

```
  19:35:43.017 WARN  org.mongodb.driver.connection - Exception thrown during connection pool background maintenance task
com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=null, userName='user', source='admin', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties={}}
    at com.mongodb.connection.SaslAuthenticator.wrapException(SaslAuthenticator.java:162)
    at com.mongodb.connection.SaslAuthenticator.access$200(SaslAuthenticator.java:39)
... many lines
```

**The question is**: how to intercept this exception in my code and be able to handle it properly ?

Comment: Issue opened: https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-mongo-client/issues/181

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the exception is not thrown, which in my opinion a mistake in design, since you receive an object that you cannot work with. Feel free to open a bug: https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-mongo-client/issues

What you can do to detect that your client is "dead or arrival" is to wait for connection timeout:

```java
    // Default is 30s, which is quite long
    JsonObject config = new JsonObject().put("serverSelectionTimeoutMS", 5_000);
    MongoClient client = MongoClient.createShared(vertx, config, "pool_name");
    client.findOne("some_collection", json1, json2, (h) -> {
        if (h.succeeded()) {
            //...
        }
        else {
            // Notify that the client is dead
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thx. I just opened an issue but it's not the only one on this very topic...

Comment: where in the code do you wait for 20 retry attempts?

Comment: I've updated my answer with how to set the connect timeout now.

Answer (score 2):

The exception is happening in the mongodb's java driver daemon thread so you cannot catch it.

Vertx MongoClient abstracts you from direct interaction with MongoDB Java driver so you can't modify anything related to the client.

You could access mongo client instance via reflection, but as it's already created you cannot pass additional configuration to it.

If you used `com.mongodb.async.client.MongoClient` you could pass `ServerListener` which could access the exception and you could examine it (please see this answer for more details - https://stackoverflow.com/a/46526000/1126831).

But it's only possible to specify the `ServerListener` in the moment of construction of the mongo client, which happens inside the Vertx MongoClient wrapper and there's no way to pass this additional configuration.