# How to set timeout on connection in `MongoClient` for VertX in Java

Tags: mongodb, vert.x

In the startup code of my application I check if the credentials for mongodb are OK. As it is not possible to intercept failures as exceptions, [I was advised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55187308/how-to-properly-handle-exceptions-in-mongoclient-for-vertx/55195211#55195211) to issue a request and wait for the timeout. Dirty, but at least it works. However I'm not able to set a different value for the timeout than the default which is set to 30s.

My configuration JSON looks like this

```
{
  "pool_name"         : "mongodb",
  "host"              : "localhost",
  "port"              : 27017,
  "db_name"           : "mydb",
  "username"          : "xxxxxxxxx",
  "password"          : "xxxxxxxxx",
  "authSource"        : "admin",
  "maxPoolSize"       : 5,
  "minPoolSize"       : 1,
  "useObjectId"       : true,
  "connectTimeoutMS"  : 5000,
  "socketTimeoutMS"   : 5000
}
```

I create the client with `MongoClient mongodb = mongodb = MongoClient.createShared(vertx, mongo_cnf, mongo_cnf.getString("pool_name"));` where `mongo_cnf` is the JSON above.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Looking at your linked previous question, which "timeout" are you actually expecting to set? As per the answer given to your question about "authorization credentials", this would not be affected by either the connection or socket timeout settings. So it's unclear what exactly you are thinking you need to set. Seems more like a driver issue and the current "solution" is to ensure your credentials are correct, in order for the driver to function "correctly". Those settings above are timeouts for TCP and not "uncaught errors", which the server responds with immediately.

Comment: Note that the answer you did not accept points to https://stackoverflow.com/a/46526000/2313887 which does correctly identify `MongoClientOptions.Builder().serverSelectionTimeout(500).build();` where the `serverSelectionTimeout()` would be the one you actually want to set. Note as the answer states this is still "hacky" since you are not trapping the authorize exception but purely where the driver failed to establish a connection of any sort.

Comment: @Neil: What I'm trying to do is to verify that the client is properly connected to the server. Failure may happen because the server is not running (in this case I would have believed `connectTimeoutMS` or `socketTimeoutMS` would be the ones to use) or because the credentials are wrong. In either case there is no point to continue and the application should exit. I just tried with `serverSelectionTimeoutMS` and it works as expected. Thanks.